# How to prevent CPU-intensive activity hanging or slowing the gui in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0

I'm doing an application that includes reading image files and displaying them in a user control designed by myself. This or other CPU-intensive activity tends to make the gui glitch and/or become unresponsive.

I'm quite aware that I should put these CPU-intensive activities in another thread, but so far I haven't found an article or example project which would give me clear guidance about dealing with these problems.

Can anyone point me to place(s) where I can find this information?

Thanks in advance.

MTH

Comment: The suggestions to use BackgroundWorker are good, but also bear in mind that 'reading image files' is not usually 'cpu intensive', it's I/O intensive.  This doesn't alter your motivation for getting it off the UI thread, but you ought to keep the difference in mind.

Comment: @Will Dean -  sure but all I/O actions are followed by processing data that was rerived and that what keeps CPU busy, i dont say that i like omitt I/O but i take it as less relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ian Griffiths wrote an [excellent answer to your question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300429.aspx) for a previous version of .NET that didn't have [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). Once you've read that essay, you should move on [this essay on doing background work and using BackgroundWorker](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.

There is a sample showing how to use it as well in the link provided :)

Comment: But should i pay more attention to that class or also/better should take more attention to threads

Comment: That is for someone with more experience in threading in .NET framework to answer :)

Comment: @MoreThanChaos It's worth learning how threads work and how to do what you're doing with plain ol' threads, but after that the BackgroundWorker class enables you to write cleaner easier-to-understand more maintainable code. As wrappers tend to do.

Answer (score 4):

Background Worker is a good choice for making GUI responsive.

1- Background worker is a event based class.

2- It raises events like ProgressReport , DoWork, WokerCompleted.

3- You just need to hookup these events and you are good to go.

4- It is very easy to use and recommnded if you are just started using threading concepts.